# Primefaces combo box do not support direction attribute

Tags: primefaces, combobox, right-to-left

I am working on application which also have Arabic version.Now JSF h:selectonemenu means combo box have pretty good attribute named 'dir' and works pretty well.but primefaces combo box do not have any attribute like this even though i am using primefaces 3.5 If I use plain jsf combo box application looses its look and feel and if I use primefaces combo box it do not support dir="RTL"
I will be thankful for some quick reply